# cross partition proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I have been having troubles in how to proof the cross partition. For what I know a partition must hold two properties:

1. The elements of the subsets that form the partition should be
   equal to U, where U is the universe set. b)
2. The subsets that form
   the partition should be disjoint or their intersection should be the
   empty set.

I have seen the following exercise related to cross partition in a book:

[image]

I can assume that I have two, or more partitions, of S that holds properties 1 and 2. So if I make a new set of partitions in Ai and Bj then these will be also partitions because I am not adding any new element to any of these subsets. From this point I make the cartesian product between Ai and Bj considering only those subsets that are common, comparing the partitions that I made before of Ai and Bj or that their intersections are not the empty set. These are also partitions because I am not adding any new element that could generate any intersection on the partitions that I have formed.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "cross-product", but if you mean "Cartesian product", then your proof is definitely wrong.

Comment: sorry @AlexM. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you have the right general idea, but your explanation is too vague and imprecise for me to be sure. Let me show you how to write up a proper proof of the result. In fact, since it’s no harder, I’ll prove the corresponding result for arbitrary partitions, not just finite ones.

> **Proposition.** Let $\mathscr{P}$ and $\mathscr{Q}$ be partitions of a set $S$. Let
>
> $$\mathscr{R}=\{P\cap Q:P\in\mathscr{P}\text{ and }Q\in\mathscr{Q}\}\setminus\{\varnothing\}\;;$$
>
> that is, $\mathscr{R}$ is the family of all non-empty sets of the form $P\cap Q$ with $P\in\mathscr{P}$ and $Q\in\mathscr{Q}$. Then $\mathscr{R}$ is a partition of $S$.

To prove the proposition, we need to verify that $\mathscr{R}$ satisfies the conditions defining what it means to be a partition of $S$. Specifically, we need to prove two things:

1. We need to show that $\bigcup\mathscr{R}=S$, i.e., that for each $x\in S$ there are a $P\in\mathscr{P}$ and a $Q\in\mathscr{Q}$ such that $x\in P\cap Q\in\mathscr{R}$.
2. We need to show that the family $\mathscr{R}$ is pairwise disjoint, i.e., that if $R_0$ and $R_1$ are distinct members of $\mathscr{R}$, then $R_0\cap R_1=\varnothing$.

To prove that $\bigcup\mathscr{R}=S$, let $x\in S$ be arbitrary. $\mathscr{P}$ is a partition of $S$, so there is a $P\in\mathscr{P}$ such that $x\in P$. And $\mathscr{Q}$ is also a partition of $S$, so there is a $Q\in\mathscr{Q}$ such that $x\in Q$. Clearly $x\in P\cap Q$, so $P\cap Q\ne\varnothing$, and therefore we have $x\in P\cap Q\in\mathscr{R}$, as desired.

To prove that $\mathscr{R}$ is pairwise disjoint, suppose that $R_0,R_1\in\mathscr{R}$. Then there are $P_0,P_1\in\mathscr{P}$ and $Q_0,Q_1\in\mathscr{Q}$ such that $R_0=P_0\cap Q_0\ne\varnothing$, and $R_1=P_1\cap Q_1\ne\varnothing$. Suppose that $R_0\cap R_1\ne\varnothing$. Then there is some $x\in S$ such that

$$x\in R_0\cap R_1=(P_0\cap Q_0)\cap(P_1\cap Q_1)=(P_0\cap P_1)\cap(Q_0\cap Q_1)\;.$$

In particular, this means that $x\in P_0\cap P_1$ and hence that $P_0\cap P_1\ne\varnothing$, i.e., that $P_0$ and $P_1$ are not disjoint. But $\mathscr{P}$ is a partition of $S$, so its members are pairwise disjoint. Thus, $P_0$ and $P_1$ cannot be distinct members of $\mathscr{P}$: it must be the case that $P_0=P_1$. An exactly similar argument shows that $Q_0=Q_1$, and it follows immediately that $R_0=R_1$. We’ve now shown that if two members of $\mathscr{R}$ are not disjoint, then they are in fact equal, and hence that distinct members of $\mathscr{R}$ must be disjoint, exactly as we wanted.

This concludes the proof that $\mathscr{R}$ is a partition of $S$.

**Added:** For a direct proof that $\mathscr{R}$ is pairwise disjoint, suppose that $R_0,R_1\in\mathscr{R}$, and $R_0\ne R_1$. Let $P_0,P_1,Q_0$, and $Q_1$ be as above. Without loss of generality we may assume that there is some $x\in R_0\setminus R_1$. Thus, $x\in P_0\cap Q_0$, and $x\notin P_1\cap Q_1$. Since $x\notin P_1\cap Q_1$, either $x\notin P_1$, or $x\notin Q_1$ (or both). Suppose that $x\notin P_1$. Then $x\in P_0\setminus P_1$, so $P_0\ne P_1$, and since $\mathscr{P}$ is a partition, it follows that $P_0\cap P_1=\varnothing$ and hence that

$$R_0\cap R_1=(P_0\cap Q_0)\cap(P_1\cap Q_1)=(P_0\cap P_1)\cap(Q_0\cap Q_1)=\varnothing\;,$$

as desired. Similarly, if $x\notin Q_1$, then $x\in Q_0\setminus Q_1$, so $Q_0\ne Q_1$, and hence $R_0\cap R_1\subseteq Q_0\cap Q_1=\varnothing$. Thus, $R_0$ and $R_1$ must be disjoint.

Comment: thank you @Brian M. Scott, one question more; the last part you are proving it by contradiction, is that right? If I want to prove it by direct proof can I say that in your the last part of your formula P0 int P1=null set and Q0 int Q1=null set also, because they are disjoint, so the intersection of both will be also null set?

Comment: @Lila: You’re welcome. What I did in the last part isn’t actually a proof by contradiction: I proved the [*contrapositive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of the desired implication. An implication $P\to Q$ is always logically equivalent to its contrapositive, $\neg Q\to\neg P$, so proving either one of them automatically proves both. A direct proof of the original implication here would require you to assume that $R_0\ne R_1$ and prove directly that $R_0\cap R_1=\varnothing$. This can be done, but it’s a lot more complicated than what I actually did or what you’re suggesting.

Comment: could you be so gentle to add the direct proof in the last part of your answer? @Brian M. Scott, I am really interested to see how to do it.

Comment: @Lila: I’ve now added it.