# $v(B)=\int_{B} f d\mu $

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have a question in integration theory:

If I have $(\Psi,\mathcal{G},\mu)$ a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f$ a $[0,\infty]$-valued measurable function on $(\Psi,\mathcal{G})$ that is finite a.s.

So my question is if I define for $B\in \mathcal{G}$ $$v(B)=\int_{B} f d\mu $$

> Is $(\Psi,\mathcal{G},v)$ a $\sigma$-finite measure space too ?

I think this reationship betwwen $v$ and $\mu$ can help me in calculational purpose.

Could someone help me? Thanks for the time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, there exists a countable collection of disjoint sets $X_i$ s.t. $\mu(X_i)<\infty$ and $\bigcup_{i\ge 1}X_i=X$. Consider $F_j=\{j-1\le f<j\}$, $j\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\{X_i\cap F_j:i,j\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{f=\infty\}$ is a countable partition of $X$, s.t. each set in the partition has finite $v$ measure.

Comment: Actually, $F_j = \{f\le j\}$ is enough. The sets don't need to be disjoint.

Comment: I don´t understand why you take $F_j$ in that form ? With this partition Do I have to apply the measure $v$?

Comment: $v(X_i\cap F_j) \le j\mu(X_i) < \infty$.

Comment: and $f$ is finite a.e...

Comment: Ok, Ok.........

Comment: Hi again, I can't prove at all this statement. I have prove that using the Monotone Convergence Theorem, as shown by the following computation: For each $F_j=\{x:j-1\leq f(x) < j\}$ $$ v(\cup_{j =1}^{\infty} F_j) = \int f I_{\cup_{j =1}^{\infty} F_j} d \mu = \int \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f I_{F_j} d \mu = $$ $$ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}  \int f I_{F_j} d \mu  = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}  v(F_j)$$ where we have assumed that the sets $F_j$ are pairwise disjoint. But my question is this $F_j $ covers completely $\Omega$ ? I don't understand why happen this and why $v$ is a finite measure ?

Comment: $\mu$ is assumed to be finite, and since $f$ is bounded on each of the
sets $F_j$, Why this implies that $v$ is finite ?

Comment: @Knight Why are u trying to show that $v$ is a finite measure? It's not. Also in the question $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: This need prove that $v$ is $\sigma$-finite and we need prove that  it is a countable union of measurable sets with finite measure.

Comment: @Knight You need to show that $v(X_i\cap F_j)<\infty$ and $X=\bigcup_{i,j}\{X_i\cap F_j\}\cup \{f=\infty\}$...

Comment: Sorry but why $v(X_i \cap F_j)$ and $X_i$ is  a countable collection that covers $\Omega$

Comment: @Knight By construction... Also look at the 3rd comment.

Comment: Yea the $X_i$ are by construction cause $\mu $ is $\sigma$- finite, and I understand that $v(X_i \cap F_j)<\infty$ but why $\{X_i\cap F_j:i,j\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{f=\infty\}$ cover all $\Omega $ too ? the $\{X_i\cap F_j:i,j\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{f=\infty\}$ that you suggest me

Comment: Is there $x\in X$ (or $\Omega$ if you like) s.t. $x\notin F_j$ for all $j$?

Comment: Not $F_j$ sorry I had a mistake, I edited

Comment: Again, can you find $x\in X$ which is not in $X_i\cap F_j$ for all $i,j$ and not in $\{f=\infty\}$?

Comment: Not really hehehe

Comment: @Knight https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718646/cross-partition-proof